# What is the meaning of "so" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was practicing with [an article](http://www.dw.com/de/mythos-deutscher-wald/l-36427818) from DW.de and the following sentence appeared peculiar to me:

> Der Wald machte den Menschen damals aber auch aus anderen Gründen Angst, **so** Professor Albrecht Lehmann.

I looked at the dictionary but wasn't able to find a satisfactory explanation for "so" in this case.

What does "so" mean exactly here? Or is there some sort of omission in the sentence?

Comment: Looking at http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/so.html, the translation that would fit this case would be "according to".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das "so" in diesem Satz ist eine vor allem in journalistischen Texten übliche kurze Form für

> ... aus anderen Gründen der Angst, **wie** Professor Albrecht Lehmann **sagt**.

Andere Formen, das auszudrücken wären:

> **Laut** Professor Albrecht Lehmann machte der Wald den Menschen damals aber noch aus anderen Gründen Angst.
>
> Der Wald machte den Menschen damals aber noch aus anderen Gründen Angst, **sagt** Professor Albrecht Lehmann.
>
> Der Wald machte den Menschen damals aber noch aus anderen Gründen Angst, **erklärt [erläutert, behauptet, versichert, konstatiert, meint...]** Professor Albrecht Lehmann.

Der Unterschied ist jeweils vor allem einer des Stils.

Außerhalb journalistischer Texte wirst du dieses "so" selten oder gar nicht finden.